# How calculating BIC or AIC with LogLoss from caret's models?

Tags: r, r-caret

I applied the equation BIC = ln(n)k - 2ln(LogLoss) but the results is not coherents. In the Caret pdf says that LogLoss is the "minus log Likelihood" ¿How I apply this likelihood in the equation of BIC or AIC?

Thank

Comment: "not coherent" doesn't help much. Can you give a reproducible example so we know exactly what you are talking about? Also, for some models, you may not be able to determine `k` or it may be greater than `n`.

Comment: Sorry. Well, the BIC's values are related linearly with AUC and TSS indexes, so the best models for the BIC are the worst models for AUC and TSS. The models are Random Forest and Neural Network, and I asumed the k like the number of predictor variables and n like the presences number

Comment: `k` is usually the number of model parameters. The issue with using the number of predictors is that it would treat a linear regression and a random forest model equally despite the latter being orders of magnitude more complex (if we could actually calculate complexity).

Comment: topepo, thank for your comment, now I understand the difficult of estimate the BIC or AIC in models like RForest. I needed the BIC to comparing two models with similar AUC and TSS, but with different number of predictor variables. I will search other way for comparing this models.